# How to get creation time(even millisecond) for file - folder in windows c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-mobile

I am working on files and folder ....How i can get the creation time of the file folder even millisecond bcoz i am facing files folder created on same second..i am able to get hr:min:sec but getting millisecond as zero when i use Fileinfo or Directoryinfo.creationtime.millisecond.....
           Plz how can i overcome this problem
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your filesystem does not store creation date that precise.

Comment: Not just likely - almost certain.

Comment: this is untrue.  Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using pinvoke to [GetFileTime](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getfiletime) and then convert to [SYSTEMTIME](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FileTimeToSystemTime.html)